# Tables to safetly truncate

Tags: indexing

I want to ask, which tables can I safely truncate in Magento, (I want to truncate all tables generated by the indexation process to make a new reindex of all my data)

Comment: Why would you do this, are you having constraint problems?

Comment: i have many products that i don t find in the indexed tables, even after a reindex process

Comment: A truncate probably won't fix your problem then.

Comment: what would be a solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Below tables you can truncate.

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
```

For the index tables if you have flat tables for category and products you can truncate or drop those after re-index system will do new entries or create again.

Tables like

```
catalog_category_flat_store_1
catalog_category_flat_store_2
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_flat_2
```

Comment: and what about the table `catalog_category_product_index`?

Comment: that table storing relation between category and products. I don't think you can truncate that.